# Cannot borrow as immutable (inside loop) because it is also borrowed as mutable

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I'm studying rust through the advent of code, and I came across an issue that I can't really work around.

In general I understand the issue that `stack1` has being borrowed as mutable (because of the pop) and I want to use as immutable in the `print_stack`.

How should I go about it, if I want to print the status of `stacks` for every iteration that mutates it?

Sorry if it's just stupid question but I'm really stuck. I've tried to clone the object without luck.

```
fn print_stack(stacks: &Vec<Vec<usize>>) -> () {
    // some logic to print the stacks.
    // for now use just println!
    println!("{:?}", stacks);
}

fn main() {
    let mut stacks: Vec<Vec<usize>> = vec![vec![], vec![1,2,3,4]];
    let stack1 = stacks.get_mut(1).unwrap();
    
    while let Some(item) = stack1.pop() {
      // something with item
      // i would like to print every step.
      print_stack(&stacks);
    }
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=eb45af19cbc7400e3c02d68d2ef9558c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Holding on to `stack1`'s borrow during the loop makes it impossible to grab a second reference to `&stacks` because `&mut` references are unique. One way to fix it is to grab `stacks[1]` fresh each iteration so the borrow isn't live during the `print_stack` call.

```
let mut stacks: Vec<Vec<usize>> = vec![vec![], vec![1,2,3,4]];

while let Some(item) = stacks[1].pop() {
    // something with item
    // i would like to print every step.
    print_stack(&stacks);
}
```